# Problems with atom-beautify as i can not beauty php code

Tags: 15.04, php, plugins, atom

A few days ago I have installed atom with a [PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-atom-text-editor-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) , I installed atom- beautifly and I I've used it for beauty html and css, but When I've tried to beauty php an error Appears :

> Could not find 'php-cs-fixer'

then I google the problem and I decided to install php-cs-fixer following the steps of [this web](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) .

Now the error does not appear but atom does not beauty php.

Answer (score 1):

With wget

```
wget https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/releases/download/v2.0.0/php-cs-fixer.phar -O php-cs-fixer
```

Or with curl

```
curl -L https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/releases/download/v2.0.0/php-cs-fixer.phar -o php-cs-fixer
sudo chmod a+x php-cs-fixer
sudo mv php-cs-fixer /usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer
```

Then add `/usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer` in **Packages / Atom Beautify -> Settings -> PHP-CS-Fixer Path**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my problem was that I installed atom via a [PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-atom-text-editor-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html). When i delete atom and i reinstalled via [the official web page](https://atom.io/) the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on **correct installing** php-cs-fixer :

```
wget https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/releases/download/v1.12.0/php-cs-fixer.phar -O php-cs-fixer
sudo chmod a+x php-cs-fixer
sudo mv php-cs-fixer /usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer
```

and now restart atom !
Hope it helps other visitors.